# FormAlchemy drop down list not setting values

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, formalchemy

All Im trying to do is set the values of a drop down list using a dictionary using formalchemy 1.3.5.

The documentation reads:

> Methods taking an options parameter will accept several ways of specifying those options:
>
> - an iterable of SQLAlchemy objects; str() of each object will be the description, and the primary key the value
> - a SQLAlchemy query; the query will be executed with all() and the objects returned evaluated as above
> - an iterable of (description, value) pairs
> - a dictionary of {description: value} pairs

I create a dictionary as is described here:

```
Location = model.meta.Session.query(model.Location)

cityCodes = {}

for row in Location:
    cityCodes.update({row.city : str(row.location_code)})
```

and include it:

```
EmpsPerson.wiw_location_code.label('Location').dropdown(options = cityCodes),
```

However, the values are still being set as the description:

```
<option value="Dubai">Dubai</option>
<option value="Portsmouth">Portsmouth</option>
<option value="Toulouse">Toulouse</option>
<option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
```

Solved:

So to fix this issue I just used:

```
for row in Location:
cityCodes.append([row.city,int(row.location_code)])

 EmpsPerson.location_code.label('Location').dropdown(options=cityCodes)
```

Comment: if dict is not supported, try to use `...(option = cityCodes.items())` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the doc is out of date. Try with a list